# Can you run xmllint within eclipse to validate xml and dtd files?

Tags: eclipse, xml-parsing, dtd, xmllint, motodev-studio

Is it possible to run xmllint inside Eclipse or Motodev? If so can someone show me? I would like to validate my DTD and XML files. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following steps to run xmllint in Eclipse:

- Click `Run > External Tools > External Tools...`
- Select the `Program`  configuration
- Click the `New`  button
- Enter a name for your external tool (xmllint in this case)
- Click the `Browse File System`  button
- Find the xmllint executable
- In the `Arguments`  field, enter the necessary arguments (XML file name)
- In the `Working Directory`  field enter the working directory (XML file path)
- Click Run

[Ant](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_my_own_external_tools%3F) can be [configured](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-tools/) to run these steps automatically for future reference.

**References**

- [Workbench User Guide > Concepts > Ant & External tools](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-exttools.htm)